# Cannot Destroy Dynamically created Menu Item in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Firstly, yes I have looked all over the net and still cannot seem to destroy dynamically created menu items.  Using Delphi XE. I create the items thus (for the purposes of the exercise SubMenuName is 'Test1':

```
MenuItemCreated := TMenuItem.Create(PopupMenu1);
MenuItemCreated.Caption:= SubMenuCaption
MenuItemCreated.Hint := SubMenuHint;
MenuItemCreated.Name := SubMenuName;
MenuItemCreated.OnClick :=  SubMenuClick;
MenuItemCreated.AutoHotkeys := maManual;
MySubMenu.Add(MenuItemCreated);
```

There is no issue using the sub-menu(s) created. The procedure SubMenuClick works as it should, and I identify the correct subMenu item so no issues there. What I then do is an application logout which is supposed to free the dynamically created sub-menus using this code (although I have tried many variations):

```
  // Get rid of the menu items created
  While MySubMenu.Count > 0 do
  begin
    Itemtodelete := MySubMenu.Items[0];
    FreeandNil(ItemtoDelete);
  end;
```

I have put in showmessage() debug lines that show the component names of the menu items being freeandnil'd and they are what I'd expect, ie. 'Test1' and any others I've created. I then log back in to my application (which was still running, but with me logged out).  The software then tries to recreate the same sub menus with the same names (as nothing has changed as far as my application is concerned and they were previously disposed of (supposedly)).  I immediately get the exception raised:

Error: A component Named Test1 already exists

I am at a complete loss as to how to dispose of the submenu items so that I can recreate them later with the same names.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
KB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You did not say it, so I have to assume that MySubMenu is a MenuItem of PopupMenu1. If not please clarify.

To delete items from MySubMenu in order to recreate them again later, it's easyest to call the Clear method:

```
procedure TForm5.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MySubMenu.Clear;
end;
```

which deletes all menu items of MySubMenu and frees their memory.

In order to recreate the items later, you can not use Delete() or Remove(), without also freeing the memory because they do not free the memory of the items. This is documented in help:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenuItem.Delete
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenuItem.Remove

With these methods you must free the memory yourself, before you recreate the menu items. But then, it's not necessary to even call Delete or Remove, you can just simply Free the items:

```
procedure TForm5.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  mi: TMenuItem;
begin
  while MySubMenu.Count > 0 do
  begin
    mi := MySubMenu.Items[0];
    mi.Free;
  end;
end;
```

There's no need to call FreeAndNil.
This last option looks very much as yours, with which you had problems when recreating the menu items. I can't reproduce the error except when using Delete() or Remove() without freeing.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Popup menu owns the items, you do not Free it. Instead of FreeAndNil use MySubMenu.Delete(0) OR more appropriately MySubMenu.Items.Clear instead of the entire While routine.

On App shutdown the popup menu will clear it, there's no need to do it manually unless you're rebuilding the menu.

Comment: Tom,

Thanks, I appreciate your response. MySubMenu is a menu item of PopupMenu1.

MySubMenu.Clear;
Still results in the same error: Error: A component Named Test1 already exists when I try to recreate the submenu item(s).
    mi := MySubMenu.Items[0];
    mi.Free;
I have previously tried this and still get the Error when trying to recreate the sub menu item(s).

Mike,

MySubMenu.Clear does compile, it just returns the same error when I try to recreate the submenu item(s).

I have previously tried MySubMenu.Delete(0) and still get the same error when I try to recreate the submenu item(s).

Comment: Why are you naming the item in the first place? Do you ever call FindComponent('Test1')? If not, then the name doesn't matter, and you're best off leaving the name empty. If you do look up your menu items by name, then you need to go find the other component with the conflicting name and do something about it. For example, give everything more meaningful names. –  Rob Kennedy 43 mins ago

Comment: Rob, I reinserted your comment because I deleted my 'Answer' (which was wrong) to a comment.  You had commented before I deleted it. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: So to respond, I thought all components 'needed a name'. Regardless, something is not right if MySubMenu.Clear isn't actually getting rid of the MenuItems under MySubMenu? In my actual code they have more meaningful names and I use the names, they provide context. I will try not naming the components and see what happens and use, say the .Hint property to provide the context.

Comment: All,Thanks for the advice, it is much appreciated. I have since found that I am somehow cycling through that bit of code twice (hence the error that the component exists).

At the moment I cannot see where this is.

Once I sort this out, I am sure I will see that all the options for freeing the component are actually working.

Again, I appreciate your time, and I've learned something which has got to be a good thing.

EDIT: Found the culprit and SubMenu.Clear does indeed work fine, again, thank you all.